# Battery Life-time on Acer Aspire Timeline-X 4830TG

Tags: nvidia, battery

I'm running 12.04. In Windows my pc lasts approximately 7-8 hours but in Ubuntu it seems like 2-3 hours. Battery time is paramount for me, so how can I fix that?

Ubuntu 12.04
i5 2450
Intel HD-300 & nVidia GT540M

Comment: Without going too much into the details, hybrid graphics always constitute a problem. Both of your graphic cards might be active simultaneously. Are you using Bumblebee (drivers for hybrid nvidia graphics)?

Answer (score 0):

ı have the same laptop enter bios choose internal graphic card....